# OSX add application menu (file/edit/view...) to app manually

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm building a OSX app and I noticed it has no "application menu" (the top left file/edit/view menu), I can't seem to find much about this other than it should be added automatically. How can I add it manually and add or remove items?

[image]

I can click it but no menu opens.

Comment: Menus are added "automatically" to the app if you have a "MainMenu.xib" in your project. If there's already one but for some reason it has no menus, you can grab "menu item" objects in Interface Builder and add them to the MainMenu.xib.

Comment: if you are building a GUI application without .xib's it is possible to create a menu without an interface builder file... but it is easier if you just use a xib